# Count different values

Tags: mysql

DB columns: person, politicalViews, region

DB example:

```
person1  liberal      Lviv
person2  communistic  Donetsk
person3  liberal      Lviv
person4  conservative Kyiv
person5  conservative Odesa
person6  conservative Lviv
person7  communistic  Kyiv
```

Expected columns: region, number of different political views of region's citizens, number of liberals in this region, number of conservative people in this region.
Expected result:

```
Lviv    2  2  1
Kyiv    2  0  1
Donetsk 1  0  0
Odesa   1  0  1
```

Obviously it will look something like this:

```
SELECT region, ?????? FROM table GROUP BY region
```

I could use a few selects, but isnt there a simple way? Something like DISTINCT(politicalViews) or COUNT(politicalViews,'liberal')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT region, count(distinct politicalViews),
 sum(politicalViews='liberal'), sum(politicalViews='conservative')
FROM table GROUP BY region;
```

Why don't you want to know how many communists are there?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in one query, using aggregates and a `GROUP BY`

```
select region,
  COUNT(DISTINCT pol_view) DiffView,
  sum(CASE WHEN pol_view = 'liberal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberLiberals,
  sum(CASE WHEN pol_view = 'conservative' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumberConservatives
from test
group by region
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0249/13)

Comment: Yea, thank you too. I accepted Michael's answer because he was first, but voted up your answer as well:)